# To compare two data having varied structure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have no programming skill at all. I was just searching web and found that python can help me with this problem.

Till now all I have done is: open the data in python using pandas and used `.str.split` to "-" to break into columns for both data. One data is what I call template data which have standard values. Other data is source which have standard data with varied values as well as data which is not covered in template data.

What I want to do is that get output data which check values with standard data and give true if below or equal the template values and false if more then template values.

Datas look somthing like this:

## Template Data:

```
A-100-50
B-C-01-80
D-E-06-75-60
F-G-H-08-15-90-I
```

## Source Data:

```
A-95-51
A-105-51
A-95-40
B-C-01-75
D-E-06-76-59
D-E-06-74-61
D-E-06-74-59
F-G-H-08-15-91-I
F-G-H-08-15-75-I
M-45-50
```

## Output:

```
Name    |Status

A-95-51 | False
A-105-51    | False
A-95-40 | True
B-C-01-75   | True
D-E-06-76-59    | False
D-E-06-74-61    | False
D-E-06-74-59    | True
F-G-H-08-15-91-I    | False
F-G-H-08-15-75-I    | True
M-45-50 | NOT FOUND
```

Only values with  in bold need to be verified.
Thanks
Hope for detailed reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have two tasks at hand:

1. parse the template data (possibly into a dictionary)
2. create a comparison function that compares two values (template vs source) and returns True/False accordingly

Here is an outline of how to do each:

1. Parse template data. We will create a parse function and we can use that, later on, to parse the source data as well.

```py
template_data = """A-**100-50**
B-C-01-**80**
D-E-06-**75-60**
F-G-H-08-15-**90**-I"""

def parse(line: str):
    """ Obtain the values before and in between the ** """
    if "**" in line:
        return line.split("**")[:2]
    else:
        # handle the case in which there are no **
        return ['', '']

template = {}
for line in template_data.split("\n"):
    k, v = parse(line)
    template[k] = v

# print(template)
# {'A-': '100-50', 'B-C-01-': '80', 'D-E-06-': '75-60', 'F-G-H-08-15-': '90'}
```

2. Comparison function. You haven't told us whether you are interpreting 74-61 to be a subtraction or just a pair of number separated by "-". I'm going to take a guess and think that they are a pair... and that it should be True only if ALL of the values are above... but if not, just adapt the function to your needs.

```py
def is_left_bigger(a, b):
    return all(map(lambda x, y: int(x) > int(y) , a.split("-"), b.split("-")))
```

Let me explain this one-liner by building it up:

- `lambda x, y: int(x) > int(y)` is just a lambda function to compare whether the integer representation of the first argument is bigger than the representation of the second argument.
- `map(lambda x, y: int(x) > int(y), a.split("-"), b.split("-"))` applies that lambda comparison function across all the elements of the two lists we are passing (which are just the separated elements of each template and source).
- finally, the `all(...)` returns True only if all elements inside it are True, and False otherwise. If you need to return True is at least one is True, then use the `any` function instead.

The final step is to just parse the source and use the template dictionary and the comparison function:

```py
source_data = """A-**95-51**
A-**105-51**
A-**95-40**
B-C-01-**75**
D-E-06-**76-59**
D-E-06-**74-61**
D-E-06-**74-59**
F-G-H-08-15-**91**-I
F-G-H-08-15-**75**-I
M-45-50"""

for line in source_data.split("\n"):
    k, v = parse(line)
    if v == "":
        print(line, " | NOT FOUND")
    else:
        print(line, " | ", is_left_bigger(template[k],v))
```

Output:

```
A-**95-51**  |  False
A-**105-51**  |  False
A-**95-40**  |  True
B-C-01-**75**  |  True
D-E-06-**76-59**  |  False
D-E-06-**74-61**  |  False
D-E-06-**74-59**  |  True
F-G-H-08-15-**91**-I  |  False
F-G-H-08-15-**75**-I  |  True
M-45-50  | NOT FOUND
```

Comment: sorry, I think I have not explained problem very well. Actually ** are not character in my string. Text and numbers are separated by only "-"
Also you are correct in assuming that these are integer values separated by "-"

Comment: In that case, you will need to adapt the `parse` function a bit to separate the keys from the values. Is there any particular format the keys/values follow? how do you know where to separate them?